# Computing the product $(\frac{d}{dx}+x)^n(-\frac{d}{dx}+x)^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

I want to compute the product
$$
(\frac{d}{dx}+x)^n(-\frac{d}{dx}+x)^n,
$$
for a natural number $n$. For $n$ equal to 0 or 1, the computation is very simple but for such a low number as 2 the brute force calculation begins to be rather cumbersome and I cannot see any pattern emerging. I tried to find some connection with the [Rodrigues' formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula) for the Hermite polynomials but I could not.

These operators come up in the algebraic approach to the [quantum harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator).

**Explicit Example**

To avoid any misunderstanding, I am going to show explicitly the computation for the case $n=1$:
$$
(\frac{d}{dx}+x)(-\frac{d}{dx}+x)=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+1+x\frac{d}{dx}-x\frac{d}{dx}+x^2=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+x^2+1.
$$

One can think of a function $f$ the operators are acting on. For example,
$$
(\frac{d}{dx}\circ x) f= (\frac{d}{dx}x)f+x\frac{d}{dx}f=(1+\frac{d}{dx})f,  
$$
then
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\circ x=1+x\frac{d}{dx}
$$

Comment: Since this is physics related, can I ask what the stand-alone differential expression $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x$ means for your context ?

Comment: I'm guessing they are using it in the operator sense. That is, order of operations matter and any derivatives are taken after all the products have been expanded.

Comment: A simple algebraic expression $(a+b)^n\cdot(b-a)^n$ is equal to $(b^2-a^2)^n$ but I most surely assume this wouldn't be the case in this particular example, as I am not totally aware of the context behind the expressions.

Comment: @Rebellos Exactly what I was going to say. This should simplify to $(-\frac{d}{dx^2} + x^2)^n,$ which can be applied termwise with the binomial theorem.

Comment: That simplification doesn't work though as operators don't commute. It simplifies to $(-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-x\frac{d}{dx}+\frac{d}{dx}x+x^2)^n$.

Comment: @Rebellos, $d/dx$ is simply the derivative operator. In this context, it is supposed that the operators are acting on some function. For example, the commutator between $d/dx$ and $x$ is computed as $[d/dx,x]f=d/dx(xf)-x(d/dx f)=f+d/dx f-d/dx f=f$, then $[d/dx,x]=1$.

Comment: @NickGuerrero, I am going to show the explicit computation to the $n=1$ case to avoid any misundersting.

Comment: @NickGuerrero Inasmuch as these operators ($\mathscr{L}^+$ and $\mathscr{L}^-$) do not commute, how would you show, as you asserted, that $$\left(\mathscr{L}^+\right)^n \left(\mathscr{L}^-\right)^n=(\mathscr{L}^+\mathscr{L}^-)^n?$$

Comment: @jobe See [THIS](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/172512/binomial-expansion-of-non-commutative-operators), which provides a discussion for $(A+B)^n$ where $[A,B]\ne 0$ (i.e., the operators do not commute).

Comment: @jobe Ah, that example clears it up

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For convenience let us rewrite $x,\partial_x$ with $a,b$ so $[a,b]=x\partial_x-\partial_x x=-1$ (in the operator sense on the Schwartz space).

> **Lemma.** For all $n\in\mathbb N$
>   $$
> [(a+b)^n,a-b]=2n(a+b)^{n-1}
> $$

*Proof.* As darij pointed out, one has $[a+b,a-b]=2$ (i.e. the case $n=1$). The trick then is
$$
\begin{split}
[(a+b)^{n+1},a-b]&=(a+b)[(a+b)^n,a-b]+[a+b,a-b](a+b)^n\\
&=(a+b)2n(a+b)^{n-1}+2(a+b)^{n}=2(n+1)(a+b)^{(n+1)-1}
\end{split}
$$
which concludes the proof via induction. $\square$

> **Proposition.** For all $n\in\mathbb N_0$
>   $$
> (a+b)^n(a-b)^n=\prod_{j=1}^n (a^2-b^2+(2j-1))
> $$

*Proof.* ($n=0$ is obvious). Note that $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2-1$. Using the previous lemma
$$
\begin{split}
(a+b)^{n+1}(a-b)^{n+1}&=[(a+b)^{n+1},a-b](a-b)^n+(a-b)(a+b)(a+b)^n(a-b)^n\\
&=2(n+1)(a+b)^n(a-b)^n +(a^2-b^2-1)(a+b)^n(a-b)^n\\
&=\big( a^2-b^2+2n+1)(a+b)^n(a-b)^n=\prod_{j=1}^{n+1} (a^2-b^2+(2j-1))
\end{split}
$$
which again concludes the proof via induction. $\square$

This result reproduces the cases (aside from $n=0$, obvious)

- $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2+1$
- Making use of $[a^2,b^2]=-4ab-2$ (similar techniques) one gets
  $$
  \begin{split}
  (a+b)^2(a-b)^2=(a^2-b^2+1)(a^2-b^2+3)&=a^4-a^2b^2-b^2a^2+4a^2-4b^2+b^4+3\\
  &=a^4-2a^2b^2-4ab+4a^2-4b^2+b^4+1
  \end{split}
  $$

etc... I feel like this formula is the best thing one can hope for in terms of structure.

*Edit:* Thanks darij for the +200 rep!

Comment: Great job! Pretty sure that a factorization into degree-$2$ factors is an answer to the OP.

Comment: Thank you! I like how we both independently considered a commutator of the form $[x^m,y]$ (my Lemma / your eq. (1)) to approach the problem...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am very happy my question has received so amazing answers, but I am having a hard time choosing which one to accept. Your answer seems to be the more explicit that is possible without becoming too complicated. I would like to have the derivative on the right side of each term, but probably that would made the result very complicated as the obtained by @Sangchul Lee.

Comment: Glad to hear so! Of course one may use further tricks to shift all the derivatives ($b$'s) to the right such as $[x^2,\partial_x^2]=-4x\partial_x-2$ etc. although I'm not sure how simple or applicable that'd end up being. Anyways, just accept whatever answer helps (or *will likely* end up helping) you the most!

Answer (score 8):

Just some Sage-generated data to play around with:

For $n = 0$, the result is $ 1 $.

For $n = 1$, the result is $ -\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} + x^{2} + 1 $.

For $n = 2$, the result is $ \frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial x^{4}} - 2 x^{2} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} - 4 \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} - 4 x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + x^{4} + 4 x^{2} + 1 $.

For $n = 3$, the result is $ -\frac{\partial^{6}}{\partial x^{6}} + 3 x^{2} \frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial x^{4}} + 9 \frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial x^{4}} + 12 x \frac{\partial^{3}}{\partial x^{3}} - 3 x^{4} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} - 18 x^{2} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} - 9 \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} - 12 x^{3} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - 36 x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + x^{6} + 9 x^{4} + 9 x^{2} - 3 $.

For $n = 4$, the result is $ \frac{\partial^{8}}{\partial x^{8}} - 4 x^{2} \frac{\partial^{6}}{\partial x^{6}} - 16 \frac{\partial^{6}}{\partial x^{6}} - 24 x \frac{\partial^{5}}{\partial x^{5}} + 6 x^{4} \frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial x^{4}} + 48 x^{2} \frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial x^{4}} + 42 \frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial x^{4}} + 48 x^{3} \frac{\partial^{3}}{\partial x^{3}} + 192 x \frac{\partial^{3}}{\partial x^{3}} - 4 x^{6} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} - 48 x^{4} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} - 36 x^{2} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} + 48 \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} - 24 x^{5} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - 192 x^{3} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - 216 x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + x^{8} + 16 x^{6} + 42 x^{4} - 48 x^{2} - 39 $.

For $n = 5$, the result is $ -\frac{\partial^{10}}{\partial x^{10}} + 5 x^{2} \frac{\partial^{8}}{\partial x^{8}} + 25 \frac{\partial^{8}}{\partial x^{8}} + 40 x \frac{\partial^{7}}{\partial x^{7}} - 10 x^{4} \frac{\partial^{6}}{\partial x^{6}} - 100 x^{2} \frac{\partial^{6}}{\partial x^{6}} - 130 \frac{\partial^{6}}{\partial x^{6}} - 120 x^{3} \frac{\partial^{5}}{\partial x^{5}} - 600 x \frac{\partial^{5}}{\partial x^{5}} + 10 x^{6} \frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial x^{4}} + 150 x^{4} \frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial x^{4}} + 150 x^{2} \frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial x^{4}} - 150 \frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial x^{4}} + 120 x^{5} \frac{\partial^{3}}{\partial x^{3}} + 1200 x^{3} \frac{\partial^{3}}{\partial x^{3}} + 1800 x \frac{\partial^{3}}{\partial x^{3}} - 5 x^{8} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} - 100 x^{6} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} - 150 x^{4} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} + 1500 x^{2} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} + 975 \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} - 40 x^{7} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - 600 x^{5} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - 1800 x^{3} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - 600 x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + x^{10} + 25 x^{8} + 130 x^{6} - 150 x^{4} - 975 x^{2} - 255 $.

For $n = 6$, the result is $ \frac{\partial^{12}}{\partial x^{12}} - 6 x^{2} \frac{\partial^{10}}{\partial x^{10}} - 36 \frac{\partial^{10}}{\partial x^{10}} - 60 x \frac{\partial^{9}}{\partial x^{9}} + 15 x^{4} \frac{\partial^{8}}{\partial x^{8}} + 180 x^{2} \frac{\partial^{8}}{\partial x^{8}} + 315 \frac{\partial^{8}}{\partial x^{8}} + 240 x^{3} \frac{\partial^{7}}{\partial x^{7}} + 1440 x \frac{\partial^{7}}{\partial x^{7}} - 20 x^{6} \frac{\partial^{6}}{\partial x^{6}} - 360 x^{4} \frac{\partial^{6}}{\partial x^{6}} - 540 x^{2} \frac{\partial^{6}}{\partial x^{6}} + 120 \frac{\partial^{6}}{\partial x^{6}} - 360 x^{5} \frac{\partial^{5}}{\partial x^{5}} - 4320 x^{3} \frac{\partial^{5}}{\partial x^{5}} - 8280 x \frac{\partial^{5}}{\partial x^{5}} + 15 x^{8} \frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial x^{4}} + 360 x^{6} \frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial x^{4}} + 450 x^{4} \frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial x^{4}} - 9000 x^{2} \frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial x^{4}} - 6525 \frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial x^{4}} + 240 x^{7} \frac{\partial^{3}}{\partial x^{3}} + 4320 x^{5} \frac{\partial^{3}}{\partial x^{3}} + 15600 x^{3} \frac{\partial^{3}}{\partial x^{3}} + 7200 x \frac{\partial^{3}}{\partial x^{3}} - 6 x^{10} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} - 180 x^{8} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} - 540 x^{6} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} + 9000 x^{4} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} + 31050 x^{2} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} + 9180 \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} - 60 x^{9} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - 1440 x^{7} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - 8280 x^{5} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - 7200 x^{3} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + 8100 x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + x^{12} + 36 x^{10} + 315 x^{8} - 120 x^{6} - 6525 x^{4} - 9180 x^{2} - 855 $.

Sage code:

```
A.<x> = DifferentialWeylAlgebra(QQ)
x, dx = A.gens()

def r(n):
    return (dx + x) ** n * (-dx + x) ** n

for i in range(7):
    print "For $n = " + str(i) + "$, the result is $" + latex(r(i)) + "$.\r\n"
```

---

Note that it is easily seen that $\left[\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} + x, - \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} + x\right] = 2$. Thus, the operators $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} + x$ and $- \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} + x$ themselves generate an isomorphic copy of the Weyl algebra, except for a scalar factor of $2$.

---

Similar numbers appear in Table X(b) of [Cayley, *Tables of the symmetric functions of the roots, to the degree $10$, for the form $1+bx+\dfrac{cx^2}{1.2}+\ldots=\left(1-\alpha x\right)\left(1-\beta x\right)\left(1-\gamma x\right)\cdots$*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RfQ7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=4320+8280+360+7200) .

---

In view of the relation $\left[\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} + x, - \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} + x\right] = 2$, perhaps the following copypasta from some of my old homework will come useful.

Let $\mathbb{N} = \left\{0,1,2,\ldots\right\}$.

Now we need an easy fact from quantum algebra:

> **Proposition 1.** Let $A$ be a ring (not necessarily commutative). Let $x\in A$ and $y\in A$ be such that $xy-yx=1$. Then, for each integer $n \geq 0$, we have
> \begin{align}
> \left(  xy\right)  ^{n}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}
> \genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n+1}{k+1}
> y^{k}x^{k},
> \end{align}
> where the curly braces denote Stirling numbers of the second kind.

*Proof of Proposition 1.* First of all, it is easy to
see that
\begin{equation}
x^{m}y=mx^{m-1}+yx^{m}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{for every }m\in\mathbb{N}
\label{darij1.pf.xy-yx.1}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
(this allows $m=0$ if $0x^{0-1}$ is interpreted as $0$). Indeed, the proof of \eqref{darij1.pf.xy-yx.1} proceeds by induction over $m$ and is straightforward enough to be left to the reader.

We will now prove Proposition 1 by induction over $n$. The
induction base is obvious, so we step to the induction step:

Let $n>0$. Assuming that $\left(  xy\right)  ^{n-1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k+1}
y^{k}x^{k}$, we need to show that $\left(  xy\right)  ^{n}=\sum\limits_{k=0}
^{n}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n+1}{k+1}
y^{k}x^{k}$.

We have
\begin{align*}
\left(  xy\right)  ^{n}  &  =\left(  xy\right)  ^{n-1}xy=\left(
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k+1}
y^{k}x^{k}\right)  xy\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(  \text{since }\left(
xy\right)  ^{n-1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k+1}
y^{k}x^{k}\right) \\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k+1}
y^{k}\underbrace{x^{k}x}_{=x^{k+1}}y=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k+1}
y^{k}\underbrace{x^{k+1}y}_{\substack{=\left(  k+1\right)  x^{k}
+yx^{k+1}\\\text{(by \eqref{darij1.pf.xy-yx.1}, applied to }m=k+1\text{)}}}\\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k+1}
y^{k}\left(  \left(  k+1\right)  x^{k}+yx^{k+1}\right) \\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k+1}
\left(  k+1\right)  y^{k}x^{k}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k+1}
\underbrace{y^{k}y}_{=y^{k+1}}x^{k+1}\\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k+1}
\left(  k+1\right)  y^{k}x^{k}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k+1}
y^{k+1}x^{k+1}\\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k+1}
\left(  k+1\right)  y^{k}x^{k}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k}
y^{k}x^{k}\\
&  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(  \text{here, we substituted }k-1\text{ for
}k\text{ in the second sum}\right) \\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k+1}
\left(  k+1\right)  y^{k}x^{k}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k}
y^{k}x^{k}\\
&  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(
\begin{array}[c]{c}
\text{here, we extended both sums by zero terms, using the fact}\\
\text{that }
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{n+1}
=
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{0}
=0\text{ whenever }n>0
\end{array}
\right) \\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\underbrace{\left(
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k+1}
\left(  k+1\right)  +
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k}
\right)  }_{\substack{=
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n+1}{k+1}
\\\text{(by the recursion formula for Stirling numbers}\\\text{of the second
kind)}}}y^{k}x^{k}\\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n+1}{k+1}
y^{k}x^{k}.
\end{align*}
This completes the induction step, and thus the inductive proof of Proposition 1.
$\blacksquare$

> **Proposition 2.** Let $A$ be a ring (not necessarily commutative). Let $x\in A$ and $y\in A$ be such that $xy-yx=1$. Then, for each integer $n \geq 0$, we have
> \begin{align}
> \left(  yx\right)  ^{n}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}
> \genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k}
> y^{k}x^{k},
> \end{align}
> where the curly braces denote Stirling numbers of the second kind.

*Proof of Proposition 2.* Just as in the proof of
Proposition 1, we show that \eqref{darij1.pf.xy-yx.1} holds.

We will now prove Proposition 2 by induction over $n$. The
induction base is obvious, so we step to the induction step:

Let $n>0$. Assuming that $\left(  yx\right)  ^{n-1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{k}
y^{k}x^{k}$, we need to show that
$\left(  yx\right)^{n}
= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k}
y^{k}x^{k}$.

We have
\begin{align*}
\left(  yx\right)  ^{n}  &  =\left(  yx\right)  ^{n-1}yx=\left(
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{k}
y^{k}x^{k}\right)  yx\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(  \text{since }\left(
yx\right)  ^{n-1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{k}
y^{k}x^{k}\right) \\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{k}
y^{k}\underbrace{x^{k}y}_{\substack{=kx^{k-1}+yx^{k}\\\text{(by
\eqref{darij1.pf.xy-yx.1}, applied to }m=k\text{)}}}x\\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{k}
y^{k}\left(  kx^{k-1}+yx^{k}\right)  x\\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{k}
ky^{k}\underbrace{x^{k-1}x}_{=x^{k}}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{k}
k\underbrace{y^{k}y}_{=y^{k+1}}\underbrace{x^{k}x}_{=x^{k+1}}\\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{k}
ky^{k}x^{k}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{k}
ky^{k+1}x^{k+1}\\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{k}
ky^{k}x^{k}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{k-1}
ky^{k}x^{k}\\
&  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(  \text{here, we substituted }k-1\text{ for
}k\text{ in the second sum}\right) \\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{k}
ky^{k}x^{k}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{k-1}
ky^{k}x^{k}\\
&  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(
\begin{array}[c]{c}
\text{here, we extended both sums by zero terms, using the fact}\\
\text{that }
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{n}
=
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{-1}
=0\text{ whenever }n>0
\end{array}
\right) \\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\underbrace{\left(
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{k}
k+
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n-1}{k-1}
\right)  }_{\substack{=
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k}
\\\text{(by the recursion formula for Stirling numbers}\\\text{of the second
kind)}}}y^{k}x^{k}\\
&  =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{0}{n}{k}
y^{k}x^{k}.
\end{align*}
This completes the induction step, and thus the inductive proof of Proposition 2.
$\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you very much for this code! I really needed something like this! The only point is that I am *desperately* looking for a **closed** formula for arbitrary $n$. Do you have any thoughts about that?

Comment: @jobe: My output doesn't give me much hope for a closed formula -- but of course, the Weyl algebra has several bases in which these elements could be expanded, and maybe one of them looks better.

Comment: Thank you for the reference , but I could not open it.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X, Y$ be operators which are *central*, meaning that $[X,Y] = XY-YX = c$ for some scalar $c$. Then

1. As a form of binomial theorem, we have

   $$ (X+Y)^n
   = \sum_{\substack{a,b,m \geq 0 \\ a+b+2m=n}} \frac{n!}{a!b!m!2^m} c^m Y^b X^a
   = \sum_{a=0}^{n} \binom{n}{a} P_{n-a}(c,Y)X^a, $$

   where $P_n$ is defined by the following sum

   $$P_n(c, x) = \sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{n!}{(n-2m)!m!2^m} c^m x^{n-2m} = \left( c\frac{d}{dx} + x \right)^n \mathbf{1}. $$

   In particular, if $c = -1$ then $P_n(-1, x) = \operatorname{He}_n(x)$, where $\operatorname{He}_n$ is the [probabilists' Hermite polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Definition). Similarly, if $c = 1$, then $P_n(1, x) = i^{-n} \operatorname{He}_n(ix)$.
2. Under the same condition, for any polynomials $f, g$ we have

   $$ f(X)g(Y) = \sum_{m \geq 0} \frac{c^m}{m!} g^{(m)}(Y)f^{(m)}(X). $$

In our case, $[\frac{d}{dx}, x] = 1$, and so, we can use both formulas to give a complicated, but still explicit expression for the product of $(\frac{d}{dx}+x)^n$ and $(-\frac{d}{dx}+x)^n$. Combining altogether,

> \begin{align*}
> &\left( \frac{d}{dx} + x \right)^n \left( -\frac{d}{dx} + x \right)^n \\
> &= \sum_{p \geq 0} \frac{1}{p!} \Bigg( \sum_{\substack{a_i, b_i, m_i \geq 0 \\ a_i+b_i+2m_i = n-p}} \frac{(-1)^{a_2+m_2} (n!)^2}{a_1!a_2!b_1!b_2!m_1!m_2!2^{m_1+m_2}} x^{b_1+b_2} \left( \frac{d}{dx} \right)^{a_1+a_2} \Bigg).
> \end{align*}

The following is a sample Mathematica code, comparing this formula with the actual answer for the case $n = 3$.

```
Coef[n_, c_, l_] := n!/(l[[1]]! l[[2]]! l[[3]]! 2^l[[3]]) c^l[[3]];
T[n_] := FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1, 2}, n];
(* Compute (x+d/dx) (x-d/dx)^n f(x) *)
n = 3;
Nest[Expand[x # + D[#, x]] &, Nest[Expand[x # - D[#, x]] &, f[x], n], n]
Sum[1/p! Sum[ Sum[ Coef[n, 1, l1] Coef[n, -1, l2]
 (-1)^l2[[2]] x^(l1[[1]] + l2[[1]]) D[f[x], 
 {x, l1[[2]] + l2[[2]]}], {l1, T[n - p]}], {l2, T[n - p]}], {p, 0, n}] // Expand
Clear[n];
```

[image: Computation]

Comment: Impressive! Your answer gives an explicit expression for the product as I have asked for, but it is indeed complicated! I am still trying to figure out how using it effectively in the problems I have in mind, but that is my fault. Thank you!

Comment: @jobe, Glad it helped! This formula may be still far from being qualified as generally useful, but a form of combinatoric interpretation of the coefficients in the expansion of $(X+Y)^n$ is available, which may possible be useful for some applications: $$\frac{n!}{(n-2m)!m!2^m}=[\text{# of $m$-matchings in $\{1,\cdots,n\}$}].$$ So $P_n(c,x)$ computes the sum of weights over all possible matchings on $\{1,\cdots,n\}$, where each matching is weighted by the factor $c^m x^{n-2m}$, i.e. each matched pair receives the weight $c$ and each unmatched vertice receives the weight $x$.